# GK local player authentication

Tags: ios, gamekit

My app supports iOS 5.x -> 6.x. It is using Game Kit. However, it says in documentation that

```
authenticateWithCompletionHandler
```

is deprecated in iOS 6.0 and I have to use

```
authenticateHandler
```

Does it mean my app will get rejected for App Store if I use `authenticateWithCompletionHandler` and claim my app should work on iOS 6 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't get rejected, but to properly future proof your app you should use "`authenticateHandler`" first before you use "`authenticateWithCompletionHandler`".

Best way to do this is to use "`respondsToSelector:`" for "`authenticateHandler`" (which I think should work on a property's accessor).